# SharePoint Framework: How to debug which dependencies are pulled into the package?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

In a SharePoint Framework web part I'm using [Office UI Fabric JS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) which works well - in the local workbench. But as soon as I deploy the web part to Office 365 some styles are missing.

Now I'm asking myself how to determine which CSS files get bundled with my SPFx solution (to see if some files are missing or the wrong one is pulled in). There are multiple instances of e.g. 'fabric.min.css' in multiple 'node_modules' subdirectories.

So this question is not really about Office UI Fabric JS, but about the general approach how to debug such things.

Is there a way to get a list of files that are bundled into my package? Like a debug switch that shows how dependencies are resolved by the toolchain?